# How to prove $ \lim \limits_{\lambda \rightarrow \infty}{\int_{1}^{2}{\frac{\cos{\lambda t}}{t\sqrt{t-1}}dt}}=0 $

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

> Prove that
>   \begin{equation}
> J = \lim\limits_{\lambda \rightarrow \infty}{\int\limits_{1}^{2}{\frac{\cos{\lambda t}}{t\sqrt{t-1}}dt}}=0
> \end{equation}

---

I tried this change of variable
\begin{equation}
q = \sqrt{t-1}\\
t = 1 + q^2\\
dt = 2qdq\\
J = \lim\limits_{\lambda \rightarrow \infty}{\int\limits_{0}^{1}{\frac{2\cos{\lambda (1 + q^2)}}{1 + q^2}dq}}
\end{equation}
So that the function doesn't have singularities anymore. Probably it is a good idea to prove that
\begin{equation}
\lim\limits_{\lambda \rightarrow \infty}{\int\limits_{0}^{1}{\frac{2e^{i \lambda (1 + z^2)}}{1 + z^2}dz}}=\lim\limits_{\lambda \rightarrow \infty}{2e^{i \lambda}\int\limits_{0}^{1}{\frac{e^{i \lambda z^2}}{1 + z^2}dz}}=0
\end{equation}
But it is really difficult do calculate this integral along any reasonable contour.

Another approach I thought of is applying Riemann–Lebesgue lemma, but I can't apply it as is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma works fine.

Put $$f(x)=\frac{1}{x\sqrt{x-1}}\chi_{(1,2)}(x)$$
then $|f(x)|\leq\frac{1}{\sqrt{x-1}}\chi_{(1,2)}(x)$, which is an $L^1$-function. Hence, since $f$ is measurable, $f\in L^1$ too, and we may apply Riemann-Lebesgue.

Comment: What is $ \chi(x,y)? $

Comment: @Peregrino it is the [characteristic function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function) on the interval $(1,2)$; if $x\in(1,2)$ we have $\chi(x)=1$ whereas if $x\not\in(1,2)$ we have $\chi(x)=0$

Comment: Right that is what I meant.